# Correct DFS traversal of graph

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, traversal, depth-first-search

[Question] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzSok.jpg)

[Attempted Answer] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qYke.jpg)

since it's DFS traversal of graph we use a stack so i visited A as it's given in the question then i went to B since it's a directed graph then to C since C doesn't have anyother directions so i have to visit back my stack i.e B now i went to D now D either leads to C or i have to move back in my stack so i moved to B (since i already visited C) B is exhausted again so i went back to A, now my A leads me to the F and it's reversable G,H don't even have a link so is it the correct way to ignore them or i should visit them aswell ? what should be the correct DFS traversal answer?

Comment: @JonChesterfield dude i already attempted the answer i can't really understand is it correct or not and if it's wrong what's the correct way of doing this? PLEASE do read question twice before downvoting or even commenting trash.

Comment: Can you post the question and your attempt as text, rather than images?

Comment: How are you defining the ordering of the edges leading from each node?

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind the DFS/BFS is that you should only visit the connected nodes while traversing not the disconnected nodes so indeed the visited nodes are correct and the order in which you have visited is also correct but you should really try to make the stack representation a little bit clear since it's tough to make out how you followed the stack in the image to your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to represent a DFS traversal is by building the corresponding spanning tree.

The graph of the figure in your question can be represented using adjacency lists that way:

```
A: B, C, F
B: C, D
C:
D: A, C
E: C, G
F: A, C
G: E
```

A DFS starting from A will only visit A, B, C, D and F and yield the following spanning tree:

[image: DFS from A]

You can add to this tree the unused edges (those ignored because they lead to allready visited vertices) and even give their classification (forward edges, backward edges and cross edges.) But the spanning tree is probably enough.

For more general consideration: a DFS is a recursive procedure (which can be simulated using a stack) that can be described this way:

```
DFS(g, cur, mark):
  mark[cur] = True
  foreach s in successors of cur in g:
    if not mark[s]:
      DFS(g, s, mark)
```

But you should already know ...

EDIT: here is a simple implementation in python that produces the dot used to build figure:

https://gist.github.com/slashvar/d4954d04352fc38356f774198e3aa86b

Comment: There won't be a F?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the F in the successors of A … I'll try to correct my answer

Comment: I think it should be A,B,C,D,F

Comment: Why is that "the" spanning tree of the supplied graph? What about "A, C, F, B, D"?

Comment: It's not the spanning tree of the graph, it's the spanning tree of the DFS. When traversing a graph with a DFS or BFS, since we visit each node with a single path (to avoid loops), the traversal describes a tree (or a forest), this tree is the spanning tree of the traversal.